# pull data with Jsoup from a table

Tags: android, jsoup

When I try to get data from a table within an online URL = forexalgerie.com, my goal is those values :

[image]

.. it seems that everything is ok with my code:

```
package marchenoiredinar.qiuworks.com.blackoumla;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new doIt().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class doIt extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String euroSell ="";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document doc =     Jsoup.connect("http://www.forexalgerie.com").get();
            Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("listEvenRow");
            for (Element el : els) {
                euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        textView.setText(euroSell);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Jsoup ListView Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

BUT .. the result contains everything inside the table except the values i want ?

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: try `euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el.html();` instead of `euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el;`

Answer (score 0):

Try `euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el.id()` instead of `euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el`

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.forexalgerie.com").get();
    Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("listEvenRow");
    for (Element el : els) {
        euroSell =  euroSell + " " + el.id();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```